# Aggregate on datetime in sql with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, group-by, aggregate-functions

The following are available [aggregate functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp) for SQL

```
AVG() - Returns the average value
COUNT() - Returns the number of rows
FIRST() - Returns the first value
LAST() - Returns the last value
MAX() - Returns the largest value
MIN() - Returns the smallest value
SUM() - Returns the sum
```

I need to apply aggregate function on datetime field? It is not listed there. Max(), Min() will not work. What I would need is either

- return the latest date
- return the earliest date

Is it possible. Can I implement it somehow?

Comment: What do you mean by Max(), Min() will not work? they work fine for me

Comment: Max() and Min() should work just fine on date fields.  Have you tried it?

Comment: what context of date/time do you mean...  You CAN do a MIN(SomeDate) as FirstDate or MAX(SomeDate) as LastDate... or do you mean sum of all orders placed on a given date, but since orders may be stamped with full time, you need the DATE ONLY portion to "group by".

Comment: That is wonderful. I probably had a syntax error then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

min() and max() work fine with dates

you can also do

latest

```
select top 1 *
from Table
order by SomeDate desc
```

earliest

```
select top 1 *
from Table
order by SomeDate
```

BTW SQL Server does not have the first() and last() functions

Answer (score 2):

Of course the `MIN` and `MAX` works..

```
Select 
    Min (MyDate) MinDate, 
    MAX (Mydate) MaxDate, 
    COUNT (Mydate) NumDates
FROM
(
    Select GETDATE() + 5 MyDate
    UNION Select GETDATE()+4
    UNION Select GETDATE()+3
    UNION Select GETDATE()+2
    UNION Select GETDATE()+1
    UNION Select GETDATE()-0
    UNION Select GETDATE()-1
    UNION Select GETDATE()-2
    UNION Select GETDATE()-3
    UNION Select GETDATE()-4
    UNION Select GETDATE()-5
) DateList
```

will return

```
MinDate                 MaxDate                 NumDates
----------------------- ----------------------- -----------
2011-11-27 13:14:47.013 2011-12-07 13:14:47.013 11

(1 row(s) affected)
```

However, not all aggregations work. `SUM`, `AVG` do not work and you will get the message:

```
Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Operand data type datetime is invalid for avg operator.
```

Comment: SUM(DATETIME) ? What does mean ?
If you want to aggregate the time past from a given RefDate, then this should do the trick: 

DATEADD(ms, SUM(ABS(DATEDIFF(ms, MyDate, RefDate))), 0)

If the DATETIME field is storing time values (DAY='1900-01-01') then you could use RefDate = 0

DATEADD(ms, SUM(ABS(DATEDIFF(ms, MyDate, 0))), 0)

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can, if the date is present as column of the table, Like  we have  one table `tbldate` which contain  Column having name `Datecolmn` .
then use the sql query to get the max value of this column  Like

```
Select Max(Datecolmn ) from tbldate
```

and it gives you the  `max date` which is present in this table.....